# Is GenericObjectPool<T> from commons.apache.org thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is `commons.apache.org.GenericObjectPool<T>` thread-safe ? I am mostly interested in  `borrowObject()` and `returnObject()` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some internet search and some personal tests to confirm the answer indeed the GenericObjectPool is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced an issue with borrow object method.
"It doesnt seems to be thread safe. " Sorry for this wrong comment. It is thread safe only.