# Is GenericObjectPools method thread safe?

Tags: java

I read article of [Is GenericObjectPools borrowObject Method thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127170/is-genericobjectpools-borrowobject-method-thread-safe). I'm getting the same issue with this, my code is:

```
public class DomDocument implements IDocBuilderPool  {
    
    private Document domDocument;
    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
    private DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory;
    
    public HashMap<org.w3c.dom.Node, DOMElement> elementMap = new HashMap<org.w3c.dom.Node, DOMElement>();
    
    public long threadID;
    
    public DomDocument() {
        setDomDocument();
        this.threadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
    
    public void setDomDocument() throws 
        this.documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        this.documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        this.documentBuilder = this.documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        this.domDocument = this.documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<Root/>".getBytes()));
    }
```

As he said constructor is un-thread-safe. As far as I know, the methods are invoked in the thread-safe stack, but why did he say the constructor in his demo is unsafe?

The problem I'm facing is that when borrow object getting the same `Connection`. Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class HsmConnectionManager {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HsmConnectionManager.class);
    
    @Resource
    private GenericKeyedObjectPool<ThriftConfigDto, TProtocol> keyedObjectPool;
    public ConnectionDto getConnection(ThriftConfigDto dto) throws BusinessException {
        if (dto == null) {
            throw new BusinessException(EnumErrorCode.SYS_HSM_CONNECTION_ERR);
        }
        Assert.notNull(dto.getIp(), "Thrift ip can not be null.");
        Assert.notNull(dto.getPort(), "Thrift port can not be null.");
        
        try {
            TProtocol protocol = keyedObjectPool.borrowObject(dto);
            CVService.Iface client = new CVService.Client(protocol);
            return new ConnectionDto(dto, protocol, client);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("com.safevast.hsm.factory -> getConnection::ThriftConfigDto = [{}]", dto);
            throw new BusinessException(EnumErrorCode.SYS_HSM_CONNECTION_ERR, e);
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class HsmProtocolFactory implements KeyedPooledObjectFactory<ThriftConfigDto, TProtocol> {
    @Override
    public PooledObject<TProtocol> makeObject(ThriftConfigDto key) throws Exception {
    
        TSocket socket = new TSocket(key.getIp(), key.getPort(), key.getMaxWait().intValue());
        socket.open();
        TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(socket);
    
        logger.debug("com.safevast.hsm.factory -> makeObject::IP = [{}], PORT = [{}]", key.getIp(), key.getPort());
        return new DefaultPooledObject<>(protocol);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What issue are you getting?

Comment: I update my question, and I'm facing that Method `getConnection` getting the same object from the pool at the same time..

Comment: Sorry, the some object just i said is not `ConnectionDto` ,but `TProtocol` inside `ConnectionDto` which borrow form pool,

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself, the `KeyedPooledObjectFactory` is absolutely thread-safe